# Is Austria out of Schengen? Can EU citizens travel there normally with IDs?

Tags: schengen, austria, event-based-effects

I read that Austria is out of Schengen for a while because of the international situation.

What does that mean?

Can European citizens still travel there with their valid EU IDs or do we need more documents, such as a visa?

Comment: Schengen is not suspended in Austria.  Travel into Austria without document checks may have been suspended, but that is only a small if visible aspect of Schengen.  Austria still participates in the common visa system and in EU freedom of movement.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the migrant crisis, Austria and several other countries around had (more) random checks at borders and other points inside the country for a while now (well "random" ... sometimes for days or weeks at the same place) .

And indeed, now it was announced that it apparently isn't going to be just random anymore (but not much details are known yet, sadly). This should be only temporary (hopefully), but a specific end date is not known currently. If you come to Autria before Friday, chances are that nothing changed until then. Currently (18.Jan.2016) it's only planned, but not yet in action.

Who may enter/leave should not change, but now a passport (etc.) will be required even for Schengen members. Strictly speaking, an ID was required before too, but most people were not checked at all during their stay in Austria. Now, it's necessary to come in in the first place.

(I'm not a lawyer.)

Comment: Your answer (last paragraph) makes it sound as if a passport is explicitly required (as opposed to a national ID). Is this really the case?

Comment: @drat, some EU member states have to mandatory ID. Otherwise national IDs are enough.

Comment: I think that information should be in the answer, as it is, it's a bit vague and also not referenced.